# windows command line evaluate inner variable expression

Tags: windows, scripting

I want to set environment variables based on a text file.
The text file has the following format
name=value

In my script i simply iterate the file and perform a set command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('type test.ini') DO (
    SET %%A
)
```

The problem is that the text file can contain something like
folder=%HOMEPATH%\test

The set command does not evaluate the %HOMEPATH% environment variable.
Instead of \Users\john\test the variables value is %HOMEPATH%\test.

Is there a way do accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `CALL SET %%A` then.

CALL will itself expand %%A and then SET will expand %HOMEPATH%.